# Why is my app graphics distorted/mixed on android?

Tags: java, android

I started developing my first real android application in Android Studio but I ran in a problem on my first run. I made a calculator app, which took 2 integers from 2 EditText's, when u pressed the button and then outputted it in a TextView. The layout looked like this: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rm196bwz8uw85s/layout.png

But when I ran it on my  nexus 7(2013) I got this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/irvwsci3gqbq8s9/distorted.jpg

Any ideas?

Oliver

Comment: Could you find anything, Oliver?